# Dot (source) command doesn't work in script, but works in terminal

Tags: shell, scripting, sh

Script file simplified for experimenting:

```
#!/bin/sh 
if test -f /home/vl/docker-test/envvars; then . /home/vl/docker-test/envvars; fi
```

envvars file content:

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
```

Nothing happens after running script, no output, no error.
Checking if env contains variable from envvars, no, it doesn't:

```
$ env | grep -i apache
```

output is empty.

But:

```
$ if test -f /home/vl/docker-test/envvars; then . /home/vl/docker-test/envvars; fi
$ env | grep -i apache
APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
```

What i'm doing wrong in my script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.` applies within the current running environment. In the first case, that's the script (and goes away when the script is done). In the second case, it's the shell. If you want the script to influence the shell it runs in, then you need to `.` it into the shell, not run it as a script.

So if your script is `bring-in-vars`, you are currently doing something like this (running it as a child):

```
./bring-in-vars
```

And you need to be doing this (sourcing it into the current shell):

```
. ./bring-in-vars
```

Children cannot, by design, modify their parents.

Comment: TY for quick answer, but running `. path/to/bring-in-vars` made no sense (./path... and . ./path... doesn't work for some reason). In fact, i'm implementing well know apache2ctl script, so i copied export vars part from there, but i'm in doubt that people run apache2ctl like . ./usr/sbin/apache2ctl

Comment: apache2ctl is not designed to set environment variables in the caller. It's designed to run apache commands. If you want to source `envvars`, then you should source `envvars`. Your question doesn't seem related to apache2ctl. The script you've listed in your question should work this way, though. What problem are you trying to actually solve? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Well ok, thank you for your explanation. I'm setting you answer as solution for theoretical part. Unfortunately, practical part doesn't work at both my systems (Ubuntu 22.04 and inside docker container based on 18.04) as i noted in my previous comment.

Comment: _What problem are you trying to actually solve?_ I've made a script to run apache inside my custom docker container without envolving apache2ctl wrapper. apache2 binary needs some env stuff in order to work, so i'm trying to set needed env values in my script (the same way as apache2ctl), but with no luck. `#!/bin/sh
set -e
if test -f /etc/apache2/envvars; then . /etc/apache2/envvars; fi
rm -f /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid > /dev/null 2>&1
exec /usr/sbin/apache2 -DFOREGROUND "$@"`